# How to persist Firebase Auth and use it to login later?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I want the feature in my app, that a user can login with multiple accounts and switch between these accounts without having to enter the email and password again.

One obvious approach that works is to persist the email-password-pairs. But that is highly insecure.

So instead I would prefer to persist the session / token of that account. And when switching the account, we logout from that account, get the session / token from the other account and use that to login.
Unfortunately I just cannot find where to get that session / token. AFAIK Firebase does what I described above internally (they persist the session / token to the SharedPreferences, and use that to authenticate the user on app start).

So how can I do that myself?
(My platform is Android)

Comment: I have provided an answer below to your question.please check

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [Authenticate with Firebase Using a Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)

> You can integrate Firebase Authentication with a custom authentication
> system by modifying your authentication server to produce custom
> signed tokens when a user successfully signs in. Your app receives
> this token and uses it to authenticate with Firebase.
>
> When users sign in to your app, send their sign-in credentials (for
> example, their username and password) to your authentication server.
> Your server checks the credentials and returns a custom token if they
> are valid.Refer this document on [create custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)
>
> After you receive the custom token from your authentication server,
> pass it to signInWithCustomToken to sign in the user:
>
> ```
> import { getAuth, signInWithCustomToken } from "firebase/auth";
>
> const auth = getAuth();
> signInWithCustomToken(auth, token)
>   .then((userCredential) => {
>     // Signed in
>     const user = userCredential.user;
>     // ...
>   })
>   .catch((error) => {
>     const errorCode = error.code;
>     const errorMessage = error.message;
>     // ...
>   });
> ```

You can also check this stackoverflow [thread](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)